# #2054 Cannot log in to the MySQL phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

At the first time I entered to phpMyAdmin with the default root user settings I changed the password of root and as well I changed the way it encrypts the password (there is two options when changing password I choosed the second one)
After that it thrown me out to reconnect with new password.
Since than I am unable to log in to phpMyAdmin and receiving the #2054 error.
I tried to change password through ssh(I think it not succeeded),
also tried to change config.inc.php settings
from

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
```

to

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
```

as well tried with password I entered in phpMyAdmin and that I tried to set in shell.
Also tried to set

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
```

And  it did not succeeded.
I hope there is a way to log in without reinstalling the phpMyAdmin.
If you need some details to help me - say what you need and how to get it.
Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstalling phpMyAdmin won't help, because you're really dealing with the MySQL authentication tables. phpMyAdmin is just a tool to access MySQL.

You should be able to leave your auth_type set to cookie if you prefer. Changing the auth_type does affect how you log in (in this case, whether or not you're prompted for the password when connecting), but it's not preventing you from connecting in this case.

To reset your password, see the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/resetting-permissions.html) for help.

Answer (score -1):

## 2002 Cannot log in to the MySQL server

i solved the above problem by simply running :
sudo service mysql start

then retrying log-on---success